# React static getDrivedStateFromProps is not working in React 16.13.1

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

Hi i am new to reactjs my react version=16.13.1.There are three files "Student.js",:Marks.js","index.js". I am trying to update state in Marks.js through Students.js using button. I am trying to update marks state through method "static getDrivedStateFromProps()".But this method is not working not even the console.log inside this method is working.Any help or suggestion will be appriciated.

```
**Index.js**
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Student from "./Student";
ReactDOM.render(<Student roll_no="101"/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```
**Student.js**
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Marks from "./Marks";
export default class Student extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            roll_no:this.props.roll_no
        }
    }
    handleClick=()=>{
        console.log("button click");
        this.setState({roll_no:(Number(this.state.roll_no)+2)});
}
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This rollNo is {this.state.roll_no}</h1>
                <Marks roll_no={this.state.roll_no}/>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```
**Marks.js**
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Marks extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log("this is marks constructor"+this.props.roll_no);
        this.state={
            mroll_no:this.props.roll_no
        };
    }
    static getDrivedStateFromProps(props,state){
        console.log("this is in marks in getDrivedStateFromProps");
        console.log(props.roll_no);
        console.log(state.mroll_no);
        if(props.roll_no!==state.mroll_no){
            return {mroll_no:props.roll_no}
        }
        return null;
    }
    render() {
        console.log("inside marks render");
        console.log("inside marks render this.props.roll_no"+this.props.roll_no);
        return (
           <div>
                <p> in Marks the roll_no is{this.state.mroll_no}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You mispelled `getDrivedStateFromProps` It's `derived`

Comment: Hey, I think you mis-spelled `getDrivedStateFromProps `. It should be `getDerivedStateFromProps`. 

Comment: Yap you r right.i misspelled. thanks for your help.now i think i should first do masters in english. ha.